# How to install latest version of tesseract-ocr in debian

Tags: debian, tesseract-ocr

I am running into the issue below:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.TSVNotSupported: TSV output not supported. Tesseract >= 
3.05 required at image_to_data (/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist 
packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py:371)
```

my tesseract -v is 3.04.01.

`sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr`

`tesseract-ocr is already the newest version (3.04.01-5)`

When I run `sudo apt install tesseract-ocr=3.05.01`, I get a version not found error.

How can I install a later version of tesseract-ocr?

My OS info:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

I have the following in my /apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main
```

Comment: Only version 3.04 of tesseract is available trough repository, you may need to compile the application from source if you want a newer version: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Compiling

Comment: In Ubuntu, the latest version is available by running `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:alex-p/tesseract-ocr` then `sudo apt update` and finally `sudo apt install  -y tesseract-ocr`. Try it, may be it will work on Debian too.

Answer (score 0):

At first check what is the latest release version [in the official documentation](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ReleaseNotes.html) or [in Github repo](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/releases).

Then check [how to install](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Installation.html) the latest release depending on your system.

On Debian Stretch the currently latest version 4.1.1 can be installed (on your own risk) from [notesalexp.org](https://notesalexp.org/tesseract-ocr/):

```
echo "deb [trusted=yes] https://notesalexp.org/tesseract-ocr/stretch/ stretch main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
# Run if you want other language packages, e.g. `tessdata_best`
echo "deb [trusted=yes] https://notesalexp.org/tesseract-ocr/tessdata_best/ stretch main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
apt-get update && apt-get install tesseract-ocr=4.1.1+git4247-97079fa3-1
```